# Does increasing the number of pipeline stages increase the throughput of the pipeline?

Tags: computer-engineering

I am facing problem with this question.

In my book it is written that throughput increases with the increase in the number of stages. But I think this is wrong. I think throughput decreases.

So can anyone please help me?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by *pipeline stages*. Do you mean lengths of pipe that increase the linear length of a single pipeline, or do you mean pipelines in parallel, similar to a manifold, or are you referring to something else? One way to increase the throughput of a pipeline is to increase the cross-sectional area of the pipeline.

Comment: Here I'm referring to instruction pipeline. Pipeline as in computer architecture

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask in computer science.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that this would be better asked on a different forum.  But here is what I know: Wikipedia basically agrees with your textbook. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining  The total amount of work to complete each instruction is always the same, regardless of the number of stages. As you add stages to the pipeline, each indidvidual stage becomes simpler. Therefore, it can run quicker. Therefore the clock speed of the processor can be increased.  So the overall processor is faster.